# How to align select tag option container in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I want to align the option container match with the select tag. I don't use any margin (or) padding as of now but still my dropdown options is shown as below:

[image]

Option container is aligned bit left.

Comment: Tried `option { text-align: center}` ?

Comment: yeah I tried...but no hope..still showing bit left...

Comment: can you put this in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
option:not(:first-child) { padding-left: 1em;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKc4d/5/)

Answer (score 1):

there is a simple way to solve this question:

```
<select>
    <option value="">--Select Category</option>
    <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp; Option One</option>
    <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp; Option Two</option>
    <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp; Option Three</option>
</select>
```

demo ---->http://jsfiddle.net/Junkie/tKc4d/6/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't possible to use `text-align` for `options`. You can try to use instead `text-indent` like this:

```
select{
    text-indent:90px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ztuq/1/)